# convert the timestamp from gmt to cst in teradata with day light savings

Tags: sql, date, calendar, teradata

I want to display the timestamp(GMT) of my table as CST with daylight savings .

From march 2nd sunday 2:00AM to November 1st sunday 2:00AM = timestamp(GMT) - 5 hours
other days of the year = timestamp(GMT) - 6 hours

It appears to be working. Now having another problem. Teradata table is having CST timestamp. Another table (different source, but loaded to teradata staging tables) has GMT. Both timestamp looks alike. But when i minus both , it doesnot give me NULL value. Timestamp looks like 12/20/2012 08:30:00.000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the datatype is a TIMESTAMP without a TIME ZONE you might simply specify the time zone you want (in TD13.10+). 'America Central' is a pre-defined time zone with daylight savings:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt ( ts TIMESTAMP(0)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO vt (TIMESTAMP'2013-03-10 07:59:00');
INSERT INTO vt (TIMESTAMP'2013-03-10 08:01:00');
INSERT INTO vt (TIMESTAMP'2013-11-03 06:59:00');
INSERT INTO vt (TIMESTAMP'2013-11-03 07:01:00');

SEL ts, ts AT 'America Central' AS CST
FROM vt
ORDER BY 1;

*** Query completed. 4 rows found. 2 columns returned.
*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.                  

                 ts                        CST        
-------------------  -------------------------        
2013-03-10 07:59:00  2013-03-10 01:59:00-06:00        
2013-03-10 08:01:00  2013-03-10 03:01:00-05:00        
2013-11-03 06:59:00  2013-11-03 01:59:00-05:00        
2013-11-03 07:01:00  2013-11-03 01:01:00-06:00
```

Comment: Table is already available with GMT timezone. I just the output of my query with CST with daylisght savings.

Comment: wrote something like this. But dont know how to add march 2nd sunday 2:00AM to November 1st sunday 2:00AM = timestamp(GMT) - 5 hours properly.

Comment: When you check the result of my sample query you'll notice it's already considering the daylight saving :-) And it shouldn't matter if the data type includes a TIME ZONE.

Comment: Ya, but i need something generic rather than for a particular year. And need to just view the output using select query. I have written something like which i have mentioned in my question. Whether any modification can be done on that?? or in ur query?

Comment: It's *not* for a particular year, it's based on the daylight savings definition for 'America Central', which is a synonym for CST/CDT :-)

Comment: That appears to be working. Now having another problem. Teradata table is having CST timestamp. Another table (different source, but loaded to teradata staging tables) has GMT. Both timestamp looks alike. But when i minus both , it doesnot give me NULL value. Timestamp looks like 12/20/2012 08:30:00.000000

Comment: @RRR - May I suggest editing your question with the additional problem. Then dnoeth can edit his answer to address it.

Comment: @RRR: can you show the actual datatypes of both columns and the actual timestamps in both columns? And why do you expect a NULL when you minus two timestamps?